# Order by asc and desc didnt give right result

Tags: mysql, max, sql-order-by

I have a problem getting result in my query .

```
id ,voteup , votedown

1  , 12     ,  7
2  ,  6     , 1 
3  ,  4     , 9 
4  ,  0     , 6
```

and my query is

```
 SELECT cm.id ,cm.voteup,cm.votedown  FROM Table1 cm  
 INNER JOIN ( select id ,MAX(voteup - votedown ) as maxe 
             from Table1 where voteup - votedown >= 5  group by id  ) tt
 on cm.id = tt.id
 ORDER BY cm.voteup DESC,cm.votedown asc,cm.id  limit 1
```

Im getting this result

```
  id, voteup , votedown
   1, 12     ,  7
```

I want to select the max result which have `voteup - votedown >= 5` first
And if two result have same result i want to order the one which have less votedown

Im wishing having this result

```
 id , voteup , votedown
  2 ,  6     , 1
```

thanks.

Here is [**sqlfiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d251/2)

I have tried to change the order of the columns like that

```
  ORDER BY cm.votedown asc ,cm.voteup DESC limit 1
```

But this also gives me wrong result if i have values like that

```
   id ,voteup , votedown

   1  , 6     ,  0
   2  , 9     , 2 
   3  ,  4     , 9 
   4  ,  0     , 6
```

which gives

```
 1,  6 , 0
```

But i want

```
2 , 9 , 2    > which is max (9-2)
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5c43/1) for this last try

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d251/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place field `maxe DESC` first, followed by `cm.votedown asc` *first* in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT cm.id ,cm.voteup,cm.votedown  FROM Table1 cm  
INNER JOIN ( 
   select id, MAX(voteup - votedown ) as maxe 
   from Table1 
   where voteup - votedown >= 5  
   group by id  
) tt on cm.id = tt.id
ORDER BY maxe DESC, cm.votedown asc, cm.voteup DESC, cm.id  limit 1
```

This query will pick the record having the *biggest* `voteup - votedown` difference. In case of ties, the query returns the record having the *smallest* `votedown` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5c43/3)

Comment: Yes it worked now thanks , Strawberry answered that also :) .thanks

Comment: There's too much query here!